# Is there a better way to say, "explain to themselves"?

Tags: word-usage

In the Common Core Standard for Mathematics, it says.."
"**1 Make sense of problems and persevere in solving them.**
Mathematically proficient students start by explaining to themselves the meaning
of a problem and looking for entry points to its solution. They analyze givens,
constraints, relationships, and goals. ..."

In my attempt to re-writing this, MS word reports that the grammar is incorrect because of **"themselves"**;  MS word would prefer I use "**them**".

Here is what I've come up with. Can someone offer an alternative and/or explain why it is wrong?

"Confidently, dive right into interpreting a problem, and explain it to themselves to look for entry points to a solution."

Comment: May I ask why the "*attempt to re-writing this*"? (Should be *rewrite*, not "*re-writing*".) It's already written.

Comment: A typo on my part!

Comment: I am making a bulleted list and wanted to highlight the notion of perseverance.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is not incorrect. Thus, you do not need to re-write it. Word processor grammar checkers don't actually speak English; instead, they use rules and heuristics that have exceptions that are correct but get flagged as incorrect.

Your version's MS Word's grammar checker is probably using some kind of heuristic to flag the word "themselves" because it could be a misused word, especially following the word "to." There are few situations where that could be correct, but many situations where "to them" would be correct--but MS Word isn't paying attention to the verb that comes before "to themselves" in order to know that this instance of "to themselves" is correct (although odd).

[This Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20them%2C%20to%20themselves&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20them%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20themselves%3B%2Cc0) shows how much more frequently the phrase "to them" occurs compared to "to themselves."

So the upshot is that you can't trust grammar checkers to be correct in all situations. They're just computer programs, and they are doing what they are told to do.

(Incidentally, the version of MS Word that I am using right now does not flag "themselves" as incorrect in the example sentence in your question.)